# Properly handling resignation when working in consulting services

Tags: resignation

I apologize in advance if this has already been answered, but I could not find something related to my issue.

I've been working for a consulting company (company A) for a couple of years. I've had multiple contracts, but my last one is the longest (company B). I've been working on site of company B since the beginning and I've stop going to the office of company A, except for performance meetings and special occasions (no more than 3 times per year). Due to Covid, I've been working from home since June last year.

I enjoy working in company B a lot, but due to my non-competition clause I've signed with company A, working for company B is impossible. I've recently received an offer for another related job that I'm going to accept. I like both of my bosses in each company and I would like to tell them face to face along with a resignation later and discuss the notice period.

Doing it with my boss from company B is easy, since it would not be weird if I decide to return to the office and schedule a meeting. However, going to the office of company A is weird. He usually calls me on the phone and tells me to go to the office due to X occasion. I'm not sure how to approach the situation to be as professional as I can be.

Is it possible to schedule a meeting with my boss at company A without leading him towards my resignation. Should I just give him a call and send him an email with my resignation letter ?

Comment: If you like and trust your bosses and you would prefer working for B instead for C, than it's worth bringing this up with A first and ask if they would drop the non-compete. They'll loose you anyway and you going to B might make score them points in the relationship.

Comment: Before assuming that working for company B is "impossible", it's worth checking the laws of your jurisdiction to make sure that your non-compete is valid and enforceable. Even if you signed it, if the law says it can't be enforced, it can't be enforced.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Never tell the customer first, always tell the manager at your employer. Your manager doesn't want to hear it from the customer without a warning from you.

If it isn't normal for you both to be in the office then you need to reach out via phone and tell them. Email should not be used to tell them this unless all other options are out.

Expect that they will want you to follow up in writing to get the process going.

I have resigned over the phone when the logistics of a face-to-face meting were too much. It avoided the dance of trying to schedule something when you wanted to not give away the message.

Comment: This!  You work for Company A not B.  Company B is Company A's customer.  Your responsibility is to let A know and they will decide how to handle things with B.  Telling B independently of A is very unprofessional.

Comment: Yes I agree. I was planning on telling company A first, then B, even though I feel like I'm more an employee of B than A.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Did you schedule a phone meeting or called when you knew the person was available.

Comment: @RegularNormalDayGuy I called them, and planned on leaving a quick neutral message if they weren't there.